# Turn on Mac with Tasker

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, tasker, macos

Is there any way to tell my iMac to turn on via tasker. If so, would both devices have to be on the same network? Is there a way to do this without being on the same network? Would my computer have to be plugged into the router or can this be done wirelessly? I guess I am trying to use wake on lan. So for instance, when I come home and tap my phone to a NFC sticker, my computer would turn on. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are talking about Wake-on-Lan. And as far as I know, the device to be awoken this way must be plugged-in via an ethernet cable (how else? when it's turned off, so is its WiFi).

As for the network: either both devices have to be in the same network, or you have port-forwarding enabled on the router connecting the different networks (otherwise your target cannot be reached).

Now for the remaining part: How to use your Android device to trigger this? You were asking for *Tasker* -- and yes, that should be possible. There is a [Locale Wake On LAN Plugin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.steelgirder.LocaleWOLPlugin) (and *Locale* plugins do work with *Tasker*. I cannot see that *Tasker* natively supports NFC -- but there's e.g. a [Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-mAbeByoNh8), so there must be a way -- hm, maybe this [Locale NFC Plugin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.badaccess.locale.nfc)?

So now there should be everything complete, and you can start testing :)

Comment: My iMac is in one room and my wireless router is in another. It is the AirPort Extreme. I have an AirPort Express. If I extend my AirPort Extreme network with the AirPort Express, and connect my iMac to the AirPort Express via an ethernet cable, will this be work for wake-on-lan?

Comment: As long you can reach it, I see nothing speaking against it, under the above mentioned conditions. Can you ping your mac from your device? Then simply give it a try, and you will know! The cable is not that expensive :)

Comment: You can wake Macbooks over Wifi, I'm not sure about iMacs. If you figure out how to send the WOL packet from Tasker, maybe this will help you with your network configuration: [How do I remotely wake my mac over Wi-Fi](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86963/how-do-i-remotely-wake-my-mac-over-wi-fi)?

Comment: Hint for that: [YAWOLA Wake On Lan](http://www.appbrain.com/app/yawola-wake-on-lan/com.mialte.yawola) has *Tasker* support (i.e. can be called from *Tasker* to accomplish that). Same for [Wake on Lan](http://www.appbrain.com/app/wake-on-lan-with-widget/at.increase.wakeonlan), and [Wol Wake on Lan Wan](http://www.appbrain.com/app/wol-wake-on-lan-wan/com.benfinnigan.wol).